# VB.NET database unable to be edited

Tags: database, vb.net

this may be a silly error within my code but when trying to create a new username and password within my program, it says "error" rather than "success". the database is linked fine as i can access it and login using the credentials but cannot create new users.

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        If txtUser.Text = "" Or txtPass.Text = "" Then
            txtUser.Text = "fill in the details"
        Else
            Try
                Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Login.accdb")
                Dim insert As String = "Insert into users (Username, Password) values('" & txtUser.Text & "','" & txtPass.Text & "');"
                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insert, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("success")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("error")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

the only issue I believe it could be is that I also have an ID section within the database that may not be incremented by 1 but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the code and I don't think it should be an issue
any help or errors noticed would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It says "error" when an exception is thrown so look at the exception to see WHY it failed. The debugger is trying to tell you what the problem is but you're ignoring it.

Comment: Also, you are opening your connection and then not bothering to close it. Bad! Create the connection object with a `Using` statement, so it will be automatically disposed and closed at the end of the block.

Comment: Also, don't use string concatenation to build SQL code. Learn to use parameters to avoid all sorts of issues. Read more [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html).

Comment: @jmcilhinney the "error" is from the MsgBox I created so I don't get a specific error message from the project itself but my own MsgBox. There isn't a specific issue but rather I can't figure out why the database is unable to be edited.

Comment: @jmcilhinney gosh the hashing fixed it! thank you so much haha!

Comment: *"I don't get a specific error message from the project"*. Of course you do. You're just ignoring it. `ex` is the exception. Guess what it contains. You may or may not choose to surface that information to the user but you're not the user; you're the developer.

Comment: `MsgBox($"Error {ex.Message}")` will include details of the error (tho not of any "inner exceptions").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue here - at least, one specific issue that I can see - is that `Password` is a reserved word in Jet/ACE SQL, so it needs to be escaped if used as an identifier. In a real-world application, you should be hashing your passwords and the column might then be named `PasswordHash`, so there's no issue. In this case though:

```sql
INSERT INTO Users (Username, [Password]) ...
```